# govendor to manager my project package,but generated vendor folder include project itself

Tags: go

I have a project with folders structure:

```
d:/gopath/src/github.com/
              ...packages
d:/projects/src/myproject/
                       main.go
                       /submodule1/
                                  ...go files
                       /submodule2/
                                  ...go files
```

`GOPATH` is `d:/gopath;d:/master`

I hava import & use `submodule1` and `submodule2` in main.go of `myproject`

Then I execute command `govendor init` and `govendor add +external` to generate vendor files.

But strange things happend, I found that there is a `myproject` folder in the vendor folder

I have try to create a new folder named `mymain` to hold `main.go`,then try again.this time there are not any files in the folder vendor except `vendor.json`

Comment: "govendor init"?  What is that?  Did you get that here, https://github.com/kardianos/govendor?  I've used https://github.com/tools/godep with some limited success.

Comment: Based on your question, you don't have `d:/projects` in your GOPATH.  Your project MUST a subordinate of a directory in your GOPATH for vendoring to work properly.